# Изменить порядок заполнения базы данных

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

У меня возник вопрос по ходу выполнения учебного проекта. Когда мой пользователь выбирает определенный набор блюд и добавляет в избранное, список идентификаторов складируется в ячейке напротив имени пользователя. Например вот так "1045, 1044, 1023", что неудобно. Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как бы мне складировать идент-ры последовательно, одно под другим, как показано на фотографии : первая ячейка графа id пользователя, вторая fav его избранных блюд. 
[Ссылка на гитхаб](https://github.com/artisakov/vigilant-journey)

Вероятно, надо сказать, что на обеих фотографиях id-пользователя совпадают, т.е. через это поле должна быть связь м/д таблицами (наугад сказано).

Код внутри manage.py :

```
@app.route('/favourites', methods=['POST','GET'])
def favour():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        list1 = request.form.getlist('row')
        str1 = ', '.join([str(elem) for elem in list1])
        con = sqlite3.connect('C:\\FFlaskApplication\\app\\database.db')  
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute('UPDATE user SET fav = ? WHERE username = ?',(str1,current_user.username))
        con.close()
        return render_template('index.html', name=current_user.username)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня заработало вот так

```
@app.route('/favourites', methods=['POST','GET'])
def favour():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        list1 = request.form.getlist('row')

        for i in range(len(list1)):
            str2 = ''.join([str(list1[i])])
            new_fav = Favourites(fav = str2, user_id = current_user.id)
            db.session.add(new_fav)
            db.session.commit()                

        return render_template('index.html', name=current_user.username
```